# Trying to develop a program to parse XML and create relational tables. Keep getting "Nonetype object has no attribute 'getitem'"

Tags: python, xml, sqlite

This assignment calls for the creation of tables and adding data using python based upon an XML file from an ITunes playlist. An example of a track's ITunes XML data is:

```
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>10.2.1</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/Users/z/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/</string>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>F343578A04A17962</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>86</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>86</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Play Your Part (Pt. 1)</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Girl Talk</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>Feed The Animals</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Mash-up</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>19612331</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>284865</integer>
```

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('tracktable.sqlite')
cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
)''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
)''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
)''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER
)''')

fname = raw_input('Enter File Name:')
if (len(fname)<1): fname = 'Library.xml'

def lookup(d,key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found: return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key:
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print 'Dict count:', len(all)
for entry in all:
    if (lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None): continue
    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')
    count = lookup(entry, 'Play Count')
    rating = lookup(entry, 'Rating')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')
    length = lookup(entry, 'Total Time')
    if name is None or artist is None or album is None:
        continue
    print name,artist,album,genre,count,rating,length

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES (?)''', (artist, ))
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name=?',(artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES (?,?)''', (album, artist_id))
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title =?', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES (?)''', (genre, ))
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name =?', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)''',
        (name, album_id, length, genre_id, rating, count))

connection.commit
```

I continue to get an error "line 75 genre_id = cur.fetchone ()[0]   TypeError:'Nonetype' object has no attribute '**getitem**'"

The previous print statement is successful in printing the genre, so I know the lookup function worked properly to return the proper value for the Genre tag. The code should have also successfully inserted the genre value into the table under the name column if I have not been given an error. Therefore, I don't understand why fetchone is returning a none value if the table has been properly filled, especially considering the [0] position is the autogenerated id column.

How can I get this code to properly assign into the genre_id variable the corresponding id number for a genre type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some albums don't have genres.

I would check to see if the `genre_id is None`, and otherwise insert a null-ish value:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
    VALUES (?)''', (genre, ))
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name =?', (genre, ))

records = cur.fetchone()
genre_id = records[0] if records else "UNKNOWN"
```